# Get the position of an element in Android's List View

Tags: android, list, view

my friend and i develop a Android programm.

Now we got to the question if it's possible to get the actual position of an ListElement.

Example: You drag the list up and down, and now you want to konw which element is on the center of the screen?

can anyone help us?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to find what value is at the center. You can maybe find out what values are visible. And you can find out the value if you click it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the ListView functions

```
getFirstVisiblePosition()
```

and

```
getLastVisiblePosition()
```

so you can calculate whats element on the center of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

There's a function [`AbsListView#pointToPosition`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#pointToPosition%28int,%20int%29) which will return the position in the adapter for the child view at the specified point. You can probably call that with half the height and width of the `ListView` to get the position for the center item. There is also [`AdapterView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html) which is one of the parents of `ListView` that has some functions for returning item positions.